# How to connect to MongoDB server using URI and server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, synchronous

I want to make synchronous queries to my mongoDB, and npm instructs me to use [mongo-sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sync) as follows:

```
var Server = require("mongo-sync").Server;
var server = new Server('127.0.0.1');
var result = server.db("test").getCollection("posts").find().toArray();
console.log(result);
server.close();
```

However, my db is on a remote location, so I have a [connection string](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) (uri). Usually, I'd use such a uri with MongoClient as shown below:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
uri = mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    // I'd read/update my DB right here
    // But this is asynchronous...
});
```

But mongo-sync doesn't have a MongoClient; it only has a server. So how do I make a connection in this case?

**Debugging Update**
I'm now getting this error:

```
Error: Error: connect ENOENT //heroku_7cr19362
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1136:14)
Followed by:
    at DB.open (/Users/Chege/NodeJS_Projects/node_modules/mongo-sync/lib/mongo-sync.js:27:13)
at Server.db (/Users/Chege/NodeJS_Projects/node_modules/mongo-sync/lib/mongo-sync.js:50:10)
at /Users/Chege/NodeJS_Projects/Constructing_the_Database/UpdateDB.js:28:22
```

The code causing the error is:

```
var mongoURI = "mongodb://heroku_7cr19362:{PASSWORD}@ds153352.mlab.com:53352/heroku_7cr19362"

Fiber(function() {
    var server = new Server("mongodb://heroku_7cr19362:{PASSWORD}@ds153352.mlab.com:53352/");
    var result = server.db('heroku_7cr19362').getCollection("songs").find().toArray();
    console.log(result);
    console.log("Last statement");
}).run();
```

So my current question is: which part of the URI goes into instantiating the server instance? Right now, I'm trying different substrings of the URI, but an explanation of what goes where and why would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Just put connection URI in place of '127.0.0.1'.

```
var Server = require("mongo-sync").Server;
var server = new Server('mongodb://someaksdmkaasdk');
var result = server.db("test").getCollection("posts").find().toArray();
console.log(result);
server.close();
```

Comment: Ok, I'm still getting `Error: connect ENOENT`


Let me add more context. mLabs connection string has the format `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds153352.mlab.com:53352/heroku_7cr459251`. 

Suppose we have a string such as `mongodb://heroku_7cr459251:h3li8jrubi4gndgl8ec6n0s5us@ds129674.mlab.com:29674/heroku_7cr459251`

What are you putting into your Server constructor?

Comment: Are you putting the db at the end of uri and then again specifying it in db("name")? Does the db exist? Is the database running? Please specify the error...

Comment: I've ran the [sample code](https://github.com/mongolab/mongodb-driver-examples/blob/master/nodejs/nodeSimpleExample.js) on Github. From the dashboard, I can see a collection named 'songs' as expected.



I think the name of the db is the last part at the end, `hero‌​ku_7cr459251`



Are you more familiar with connecting straight to MongoDB Atlas? I can adjust the code to query a db hosted on Atlas to suit your expertise.

Comment: @Chege, Can you please specify the error clearly if you don't mind?

Comment: Will do. Let me move to a new comment so that I can get the formatting right.

Comment: @Ravikumar, I've updated the question to show you the code and error.